# retrive records where updated_at is not older than X seconds in Laravel (eloquent)

Tags: laravel, timestamp, eloquent

Following the examples found here on stack overflow I'm trying to do this:

```
$users = User::where('updated_at', '>', time() - (5))->get();
```

As the title of the post, I would like to receive only the records where the field "updated_at" is not older than 5 seconds. I also tried something like that:

```
...where('updated_at', '<', DB::raw('(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)'))...
```

or

```
...where('updated_at', '>=', time() - (1*1*5))->get();
```

but keeps giving me even the obsolete records...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This way:

```
$users = User::where('updated_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(5)->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

Comment: Maybe this was working 2 years ago with laravel 4. Now you should add to the end of Carbon chain ->toDateTimeString(). Shouldn't you? (\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(5) is returning carbon object not the datetimestring wanted)

Comment: i was looking for this. It worked 2 years ago but with laravel 5.3 it doesn't work as @koalaok mentioned